Scala having issues with Lexical parsing ; or false
Hello I have a formula
child(1);false and I am trying to parse it. I have tried several variations but somehow none of them are working
"child" ~ "(" ~> numericLit <~ ");false" ^^
"child" ~ "(" ~> numericLit <~ ")" ~ ";false" ^^
"child" ~ "(" ~> numericLit <~ ")" ~ ";" ~ "false" ^^

If I try to match child(1) it works but as soon as I try with child(1);false I get error from the parser end of input expected
this is returned from the built in parser function which looks like this
  def phrase[T](p: Parser[T]) = new Parser[T] {
    def apply(in: Input) = p(in) match {
      case s @ Success(out, in1) =>
        if (in1.atEnd) s
        else Failure("end of input expected", in1)
      case ns => ns
    }
  }

I am quite clueless what to do and would appreciate help in this

Did you tried "child(" ~> numericLit <~ ");false" ^^?

Which parsing library are you using?

yeah i did try this one as well but it doesn't works too

 "child" ~ "(" ~> numericLit ~ ")" ~ opt(";" ~ booleanLit) ^^ { a =>
        val childArgument = Argument(Right("child"), Some(Argument(Left(a._1._1.toInt), None)))
        val optionalArgument = if (a._2.nonEmpty) {
          Some(Argument(Left(if (a._2.get._2) 1 else 0), None))
        } else
          None
        if (optionalArgument.nonEmpty) {
          List(childArgument, optionalArgument.get)
        } else {
          List(childArgument)
        }
      }

def booleanLit: Parser[Boolean] =
    "true" ^^ { _ => true } | "false" ^^ { _ => false}

this is how it was solved. there were three cases child(1), child(1);false and child(1);true
